# regular expression to say either string ends or continues with specific character

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex that will match if the string starts with `"PR-\d+"`, but then either the string ends, or the next character is a hyphen.  So, for instance, the following would match:

```
PR-123
PR-123-foo
```

But the following would not:

```
PR-123a
PR-
PR-foo
```

I tried `re.match(r'PR-\d+[-$]', st)`, but that didn't work.  It appears that this is searching for the literal dollar sign character, rather than end of string.

How can I write this expression?

Comment: Perhaps, you need [`re.match(r'PR-\d+(?:-|$)', st)`](https://regex101.com/r/hB4D7P/1)

Comment: looks like that did it.  go ahead and post an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I added several variations and explanations to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825095/3832970). Note that a negative lookahead with negated character class solution is a bit more efficient than a with positive lookahead with alternation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dollar sign inside a character class is parsed as a literal `$` char. You need to use an alternation group, or a positive lookahead.

Here is a version with a non-capturing group:

```
re.match(r'PR-\d+(?:-|$)', st)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB4D7P/1).

A positive lookahead version:

```
re.match(r'PR-\d+(?=-|$)', st)
```

Or the identically working negative lookahead solution coupled with a negated character class (so as to avoid the alternation and make the pattern *a tiny bit more efficient*):

```
re.match(r'PR-\d+(?![^-])', st)
```

The only difference is what these regex matches return: the non-capturing group version will actually return the `-` as part of the match value, and the second one will not contain that `-` char. There is no difference if you are just checking for a match.

And just FYI: `re.match` will only look for a match at the start of the string, that is why there is no need using `^` at the start of the pattern. Else, if you were to use `re.search` or other non-anchoring methods, you would have to prepend the pattern with `^` or `\A` anchors that match the start of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a double negation with a negative lookahead and a negative character class:

```
re.match(r'PR-\d+(?![^-])', st)
```

In plain english: not followed by a character that isn't an hyphen.

This description handles the two cases: followed by an hyphen or followed by the end of the string.

[demo](https://eval.in/987997)

Answer (score -2):

`r"PR-\d+[-\w+]*$"` It works, I tested it

Comment: Maybe you should test it?

Comment: This does not work correctly. It allows any number of word characters between the number and the end of the string, making it match things like `PR-123a`.